# Remote Desktop - Client to Client

Tags: remote, desktop

Hello fellow IT specialists,

I have a network set up with one Domain Controller (Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit) which is also my DHCP and DNS and AD server. I have several Windows 7 Professional 64-bit desktop clients on my domain.

I would like to know how I can use Windows Remote Desktop to remote in from one Windows 7 Professional desktop client to another Windows 7 Professional desktop client.

I have enabled Remote Desktop in the server's Windows Firewall for this but I still can't seem to be able to remote from Windows 7 to Windows 7.

I then have created a Group Policy object enabling the Windows Remote Desktop it is being applied successfully but it still does not let me Remote Desktop from one Windows 7 client to another.

Please can you advise me where I am going wrong or what else I should do to enable Windows Remote Desktop from Windows 7 to another Windows 7 client.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Well, you need to enable remote desktop connections on the clients.  And you need to be able to connect to those clients.  On the right port (3389 by default).

Comment: Okay, can this be done through Group Policy or something like a script etc as I have several Windows 7 clients?

Comment: Yup, and someone posted a link on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do this through Group Policy. Yup:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4980.how-to-enable-or-disable-remote-desktop-via-group-policy-windows-2008.aspx

I found this by googling "group policy enable remote desktop"

Comment: If you set this with a GP, then you need to also enable the firewall exception with a GP.  The exception doesn't happen automatically like when you check the box in the GUI.

Comment: Thanks to you all. I'll try this out on Monday and let you know when I have implemented this.